# Can we use static type variables in web application, which will be used by many users at the same time?

Tags: c#-4.0

```
    private static List<string> _Process;
    public List<string> Process
    {
        get { return _Process; }
        set { _Process = value; }
    }

    private static string _IDsCombination;
    public string IDsCombination
    {
        get { return _IDsCombination; }
        set { _IDsCombination = value; }
    }

    private static int _QCID;
    public int QCID
    {
        get { return _QCID; }
        set { _QCID = value; }
    }
```

As above, i have created some static variables, does they share the same memory for all the users.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: most likely yes.**

**Long answer:** 
Static members are shared across the application domain.

If you are running your website in just one web application, on a single server, then **yes**. This is common for small web applications.

However, if you are running on multiple servers/web applications (say in a web farm), then they are **not shared** between those (just like inProc session is not shared). If you are running in this kind of environment, then you need to look at other solutions like saving it in a database or a cache server.

Also, if you plan to do this, you should make accesses thread safe. See: [Multithreading (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx). In this particular example, you might want to use a `ReaderWriterLock` or a `Mutex`

Comment: So if i do not want share a particular variable between all the users, then what is the prefered method to save the value of a variable during postbacks? should i save it in sessions? One more thing, if i want to save datatables in sessions, is it good to go or not? Where i can seve Datatables during postbacks?

Comment: @user2661571 You could session or viewstate (if available). Personally, I don't like storing large amounts of data in session. It could cause memory pressure on large sites or shared hosting environments. Viewstate on the other head, serializes the data so there are restrictions on what can be stored (haven't tried Datatables though). It doesn't use up memory for storage but makes your pages bigger and has to be sent on each postback/response, and so uses up bandwith. In most scenarios, I'd store the absolute minimum and just retrieve the rest when I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes
Because Codes run on the server and it's share between All Users